# Like/Dislikes in 5 star ratings

Tags: math

What is the formula for a 5 star rating if I only have likes/dislikes.

If I have 3244 likes and 45 dislikes how much would that be from 0-5 stars in rating ? (4.9 something, how do I calculate it though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you could just use:

```
likes / (likes + dislikes) * 5
```

So for your example, `3244 / (3244 + 45) * 5 = 4.93`. I'll leave it to you to convert this simple formula to Mathematica code.